# How to invoke app from my pipeline in a locally hosted agent?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, signtool

I have created a test pipeline that will work with a Github repository to build a simple C# console app. I have also created my local Agent that runs on the default pool and shows as `online`. When I try to run a step that looks like this:

```
- script: signtool sign /sha1 ... /tr ... $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\MyApp.exe
  displayName: "Sign File"
```

I receive the following output:

```
'signtool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.
```

How can the local agent be allowed to execute existing cmd apps from the host workstation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use utility task in YAML `CmdLine@2` , and follow pattern like this , this is a simple echo script to output in your console.

```
# Command line
# Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: 'echo Write your commands here.' 
    #workingDirectory: # Optional
    #failOnStderr: false # Optional
```

Answer (score 0):

Your try is good

```yaml
- script: signtool sign ...
  displayName: "Sign File"
```

but please make sure you are in the correct folder. If you already build you app and have it on the agent please locate it first. Check logs for instance to find your correct path. You can also list currect directory:

```
- script: |
    ls .
    signtool sign ...
  displayName: "Sign File"
```

Please check what is inside.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did update the question a little bit adding the full `sign` command. I can verify that the `.exe` is in the expected location.